# What's the proper way to construct a signal/slot wrapper to a blocking call?

Tags: c++, qt, asynchronous, signals, blocking

Suppose I have a `QObject` and a blocking method (say, it's a library call that needs to fetch a lot of data from the network before returning).

```
class Foo : public QObject { 
Bar* _bar;
public:
    // non blocking call, emits stuffDone when done
    void startStuff(int a, int b);
signals:
    void stuffDone(int sum);
}


class Bar {
public:
    // Blocking call
    int doStuff(int a, b) { 
        for(int i=0; i<=100000000000; i++);
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

I'd like my `Foo::startStuff` method to run `doStuff` in the appropriate (separate) thread and trigger a `stuffDone` signal upon completion.
`startStuff` would have to return immediately.

`Bar` *can* be a QObject if necessary, thus allowing for setting thread affinity via `moveToThread`

What is the simplest and most idiomatic ('Qt-like') way of doing so?

Comment: The [documentation to QThread](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.5/qthread.html) seems to give you two simple answers to your question. Is there any reason why you can't use those?

Comment: @Rostislav That documentation doesn't give the entire picture. Instantiating threads manually, instead of using the thread pool, is generally a bad idea. Threads are expensive.

Comment: @Rostislav: Not really, but I wonder if that's the "correct" way - or rather, I wonder if the "correct" way necessarily implies turning my library into a QThread or adding signals to it, which would basically mean wrapping it into a second wrapper. It seems a tad verbose and awkward in general.

Comment: To run things asynchronously to completion, you shouldn't ever need to use explicit threads - the thread pool is what you should use instead.

Comment: @KubaOber Thread pools are great - I'm using them myself in my application. However, I wouldn't agree with using them always. In case the thread would spend most of its time waiting for I/O - it's a good candidate for NOT putting it into a thread pool - the OS will do a much better job of scheduling it. Thread pool, however, will not let some other task even run before the previous one ends (if pool has more threads - then N tasks waiting for I/O will prevent next task from running). For such tasks QFuture would indeed be better. For computationally intensive tasks - thread pools are better.

Comment: @Rostislav `QtConcurrent::run` & co., the creators of futures, takes threads from a thread pool... you can pass it a thread pool, or use the default global instance. If a thread is mostly blocking for I/O, you should fix the code that blocks. Threads are way too expensive to waste on stupid blocking code.

Comment: @KubaOber Yep, I'm wrong regarding the QtConcurrent. Could you clarify your view on the I/O threads though. Consider a simple task of writing several 100MB of data to 4 hard drives (different data for each drive) on 4 hardware thread machine. Putting write tasks into a thread pool seems to be a waste (as they will be mostly waiting the disk) and spending micro or milliseconds for creating a thread is negligible for threads that will run seconds and OS should handle them cheaply. I know it's a bit of a vague discussion, but what would you do in this case?

Comment: @KubaOber In short (e.g.  answer like boost::asio or just the name of some qt api or whatever would be great)

Comment: @Rostislav (This is Windows-only) `QFile` doesn't provide async support on any platform, so you have to reimplement `QIODevice` for generic handles using one of the overlapped I/O notification schemes (completion routines, event signaling or I/O completion ports). Completion routines and event signaling are compatible with Qt's event loop implementation on Windows. Dedicated threads are needed for completion ports, but you can implement your own worker queue on top of them. Async file I/O support on Unices varies. On Linux it's a snafu.

Comment: @KubaOber Thanks for the detailed answer! Well, in my opinion, saving 10 or even 100ms for creating a thread would not be worth all the hassle in _the_ _particular_ _case_ _I_ _described_. But it all depends on a specific application and more importantly, measure-measure-measure :)

Comment: @Rostislav I don't think you should ever be creating threads at all past the startup..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`QtConcurrent::run` would probably be most idiomatic:

```
struct Bar {
   // Blocks for 3 seconds
   int doStuff(int a, b) { 
      QThread::sleep(3);
      return a+b+42;
   }
};

class Foo : public QObject {
   Q_OBJECT
   Bar _bar;
public:
   // Non-blocking, emits stuffDone when done
   void startStuff(int a, int b) {
      QtConcurrent::run([a,b,this]{
         auto result = _bar.doStuff(a,b);
         emit stuffDone(result);
      });
   }
   Q_SIGNAL void stuffDone(int sum);
};
```

Instead of using the custom `Foo` class, you could also use a `QFutureWatcher`, but IMHO it's more cumbersome as there's no signal that provides the result - you'd need to connect a functor that works on the result.

```
QSharedPointer<Bar> bar { new Bar };
auto watcher = new QFutureWatcher<int>;
connect(watcher, &QFutureWatcher::finished, watcher, [watcher, bar]{
  watcher->deleteLater();
  int result = watcher->result();
  // use the result here
});
auto future = QtConcurrent::run(&Bar::doStuff, bar, 1, 2);
watcher->setFuture(future);
```

Note that the "long" addition loop is usually optimized out since it has no side effects and is thus dead code. If you want to simulate blocking, use `QThread::[|m|u]sleep`.

Comment: Thanks. In fact, my Foo does a bunch of *other* things as well. I was wondering, is there a particular reason for the `auto`? I'd rather stay in C++98 mode.

Comment: @TobiaTesan There's no way to write sane Qt 5 code without lambdas, so you do need C++11. They are supported since MSVC2010 on Windows, and by most other compilers earlier than that. Staying in C++98 mode with Qt 5 forces you to do way more typing than necessary - e.g. you have to declare methods instead of anonymous functors, etc.

Comment: thank you. @Future Reader: please *do* remember to **add `CONFIG += c++11`** to your `.pro` file, lest you waste away an entire morning trying to figure out the problem... as I just did.

Comment: @TobiaTesan That's only necessary on Unices, though.