# How can I join a Thread running a function from the mainWindow class (Principal)?

Tags: qt, function, compiler-errors, pthreads, qt-creator

I got this Error Message when I compile my project:

"Can not convert 'Principal::setValues' from type 'void*(Principal::)(void*)' to type 'void*(*)(void*)' "
...

```
enter code here 
void* Principal:: setValues(void*){
    QString velocidadCARGA=QString::number(VelocidadCargador);    
    QString velocidadLAVA=QString::number(VelocidadLavado);
    ui->Velocidad_Carga->setText(velocidadCARGA);
    ui->Velocidad_Lavado->setText(velocidadLAVA);
    ui->lbl_CantidadActual_Banda_Principal->setNum(botellasCargadas);
    return NULL;
}


void Principal::on_Start_Cargador_clicked(){
    pthread_t hilo3;
    pthread_create(&hilo3,NULL,setValues,NULL);//error in this line.
    pthread_join(hilo3,NULL);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Principal::setValues` is a member function, so its type does not conform with a function type required by `pthread_create`.

To launch a member function in a thread you can declare some static method and pass `this` object into it:

```
class Principal
{
...
static void* setValuesThread(void *data);
...
}

void* Principal::setValuesThread(void *data)
{
    Principal *self = reinterpret_cast<Principal*>(data);
    self->setValues();
    return NULL;
}

// your code
void Principal::setValues()
{
    QString velocidadCARGA=QString::number(VelocidadCargador);    
    QString velocidadLAVA=QString::number(VelocidadLavado);
    ui->Velocidad_Carga->setText(velocidadCARGA);
    ui->Velocidad_Lavado->setText(velocidadLAVA);
    ui->lbl_CantidadActual_Banda_Principal->setNum(botellasCargadas);
}

void Principal::on_Start_Cargador_clicked()
{
    pthread_t hilo3;
    pthread_create(&hilo3, NULL, Principal::setValuesThread, this);
    pthread_join(hilo3,NULL);
}
```

But if `Principal` is a Qt widget (and I suppose it is), this code won't work because in Qt you can access widgets from the main thread only.

If you want to have some heavy calculations in a worker thread and then pass the results to your widget, you can use `QThread` and Qt signals/slots mechanism.

A simple example:

```
class MyThread : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyThread(QObject *parent = 0);

    void run();

signals:
    void dataReady(QString data);
}

void MyThread::run()
{
    QString data = "Some data calculated in this worker thread";
    emit dataReady(data);
}

class Principal
{
...
public slots:
   void setData(QString data);
}

void Principal::setData(QString data)
{
    ui->someLabel->setText(data);
}

void Principal::on_Start_Cargador_clicked()
{
    MyThread *thread = new MyThread;
    connect(thread, SIGNAL(dataReady(QString)), this, SLOT(setData(QString()));
    connect(thread, SIGNAL(finished()), thread, SLOT(deleteLater()));
    thread->start();
}
```

Here is some related articles on Qt multithreading technologies:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/thread-basics.html

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-technologies.html

Comment: It is a premature pessimization to have threads that exist only for the duration of a computation. Such computations should be done using [`QtConcurrent::run`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32507937/1329652) on either a global or a dedicated thread pool.

Comment: In your example you create a `QObject` wrapper for `QtConcurrent::run` call just to be able to send a Qt signal about it was finished. Isn't it a premature pessimization too? I think in this simple exmaple it doesn't really matter which Qt multithreading technique one should use.

Comment: You do the same. Just because your object derives from `QThread` doesn't make it special. What matters is that you should be using an existing thread, not making a new one.

Comment: I don't say my object is special. I want to say that for a simple example you can use any high-level Qt wrapper for a thread: `QThread`, `QtConcurrent::run` or `QThreadPool`. Internally all of them will do almost the same. I know that for an actual task one should pick a tool that suits that actual task best.

Comment: `QtConcurrent::run` simply uses a `QThreadPool`, so let's see what's the difference between using a `QThread` vs. `QThreadPool`. The thread pool does not finish the threads that aren't used at the time, it keeps them active. When you use a `QThread` directly, you force the thread to exist only for as long as your computations take: when `run()` exits, the thread ceases to exist (even though `QThread` exists!). This is wasteful and a premature pessimization. *Running* threads should be created/destroyed rarely. A `QObject` costs next to nothing compared to `QThread::start`/returning from run().